# matlab for loop hang

Tags: matlab, for-loop, logic

i am doing a simulation and code for a for loops

for example

```
IntervalInterArrivalTime = [2 3 4 5] //user input 
CDF = [250 500 750 1000] // this is the probability but multiply 1000 to alculate the range
randInterArrival = [991 351 754 823] // this is pc random generated number so each time wwill be different 

lengthCDF = length(CDF); // length of the CDF which in this case is =4
period = 0;
```

the for loop i want do is the program will check the range of the randInterArrival with the CDF and IntervalArrivalTime. For example:

if randInterArrival >0 and <= CDF(1) , then period will be IntervalInterArrivalTime(1)

else if randInterArrival > CDF(1) and <= CDF(2) , then the period will be IntervalInterArrival(2)

else if randInterArrival > CDF(2) and <= CDF(3) , then the period will be IntervalInterArrival(3)

else if randInterArrival > CDF(3) and <= CDF(4) , then the period will be IntervalInterArrival(4)

```
for i=1:lengthCDF
if randInterArrival(i)>0 && randInterArrival(i)< CDF(i)
 period=IntervalInterArrivalTime(i)
else if randInterArrival(i)> CDF(i) % how to continued to write the statement out so that i can loop through all the items in the CDF and check which IntervalInterArrival() it is

% i stop here and dunno how to continued to loop through the CDF and check
end
end
```

hope u all can help . thanks in advance

Comment: first, your if statement is funky.  see here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html. you either need to use elseif or else and end for the else.  you also need to end your for loop.  and take away the noose if you don't want your code to hang.

Comment: i know i didnt end the file because the for loop havent finish yet. and i have try a few way to do the for loop but still fail. can give a similiar example so that i can let the for loop to loop and check through the CDF ?  thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you post the actual code because "else if randInterArrival(i)> CDF(i) && ?? // i hang here .. " doesn't look like legit matlab code.  I think people will be able to help you better if you post the original code.

Comment: my actual code contains a lot of fig automated code. so i just take out part of it. the things i want to ask is 

if the how to compare the randInterArrival(i) item with the CDF item.

Comment: guys, this is a confusion. not MATLAB hangs here but @Eric as in "he is stuck".

Comment: ya .. i means i am stuck there and dunno how to continued to do the for loop ... sorry if my meanings have been confused you 

and thanks @s.bandara :) any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do this the way you're proposing, by checking each condition separately.  However, this gets obnoxiously clunky as you increase the number of elements/conditions to check.  A better way is to make use of the `find` function and *rethink the logic of what you're trying to do:*

What is the goal? The goal is to determine the index of the smallest `CDF` value that is larger than `randInterArrival(i)`.  Do this as follows:

```
index = find(CDF > randInterArrival(i), 1, 'first');
```

Voila! No `if` statements necessary.  Use this index to get the period:

```
period = IntervalInterArrivalTime(index);
```

Comment: thanks @tmpearce using this method i don't need to use the if statement which is very confusing . thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `end` your statements:

```
for i=1:lengthCDF
if randInterArrival(i)>0 && randInterArrival(i)< CDF(i)
 period=IntervalInterArrivalTime(i)
else if randInterArrival(i)> CDF(i) && ?? // i hang here .. 
end
end
```

Comment: i know i need to end the statement .. but the for loop havent finish run yet and i dunno how to continued for the for loop . u know how to do that ???

Comment: are you typing this code into the command line?  if so, why don't you just write it into a .m file.

Comment: i am writing it to a .m file . the things i dunno is the for loop. how to loop it so that i can check all the variables inside the CDF